# What kind of DB support does Infinispan offer?

Tags: infinispan

I don't want to use Infinispan as my data source.  What kind of DB support is offered?  Will Hibernate 2nd-Level Cache be necessary?

Answer (score 7):

Infinispan can be configured with a persistent cache loader and amongst the supported options, JDBC based cache stores are supported. You can find all about them, including the JDBC one, in https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Cache+Loaders+and+Stores - There're some sample configurations there too.